# Error calling member function as constructor parameter "Variable is not a type name"

Tags: c++, sfml

I would like to pass the output of a member function of a local instance as a parameter for my constructor. I am using the SFML library.

Ball.h

```
    Ball(sf::Vector2f _dvelocity, sf::Vector2f _position, sf::Vector2f _origin, sf::Texture _texture, float _dvmagnitude )
    {
        dvelocity = _dvelocity;
        position = _position;
        sprite.setTexture(_texture);
        sprite.setOrigin(_origin);
        dvmagnitude = _dvmagnitude;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Pong");
    sf::Event event;
    sf::Texture pongTexture;
    pongTexture.loadFromFile("frost mage.PNG");
    Ball ball(sf::Vector2f _dvelocity(), sf::Vector2f _position(), window.getSize(), pongTexture, 1);
```

The error is triggered by "window.getSize()" in the last line of main.cpp. My debugger reads, "window is not a type name."

Comment: `sf::Vector2f _dvelocity()` is not how you call a function. `_dvelocity()` is how you call a function. That line starting with `Ball ball` doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do there? To the compiler, it starts looking like you are trying to declare a function named `ball` that returns `Ball` and takes a function pointer as a parameter - until it gets to `window.getSize()` which doesn't look like a function parameter. But my guess is, you didn't mean that line to look like a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your constructor definiton, where you are taking `sf::Vector2f _origin`parameter and then `window.getSize()` returns `sf::Vector2U`. Try changing your parameter to `sf::Vector2U _origin`.